# Errors while using Vue CLI 4 and A Frame

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe

I have been trying to develop a VR web app using Vue cli 4.2.3 and aframe.io
And got a lot of error messages like these for all of aframe's components

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <a-scene> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <a-cursor> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

here is my main.js code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import 'aframe';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

For convenience I will just write the link from which I'm having reference.
both has literally same code

https://github.com/nobu222/aframe-vue-sample/blob/master/src/App.vue

https://github.com/nobu222/aframe-vue-sample/blob/master/src/Entity.vue

Please help me guys. This thing is really giving me headache

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that these components in snake case collide with Vue. Vue can't find those components registered, so you get the error that you do.

The short of it: tell `Vue` to `ignoreElements` associated with `a frame`:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'a-scene',
  'a-entity',
  'a-camera',
  'a-box',
  'a-sky',
  'a-sphere',
  'a-cylinder',
  'a-plane'
];
```

The above list isn't comprehensive, but is a starting point. You can add more to it or subtract from it as you please.